# Virtualbox ubuntu 14 - zbar barcode reader loads and camera shows indicator light, but see nothing

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, virtualbox

I installed zbar barcode reader on my virtualbox ubuntu 14.04. I loads as shown below and the camera indicator light also lights up, but I don't see anything on the screen. I only see the zbar logo.

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work try these steps:

1. Add your user to the `vboxusers` group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
   ```
2. Then restart system to have it picked up.
3. In Virtualbox click on `Devices` at the top under `Webcams` select your device to add it.

   [image]

That's how it worked for me:

Comment: my device doesnt show up in webcam, but it shows up in usb.

Comment: Then add it from there mines built in.